Kotlin Compose Google SignIn with Firebase returns null
I'm trying to create a button in my kotlin compose app that lets users to sign in with a google account. To do so I've realizaed the code below that sends a request to firebase but instead of receiving an IntentSender I always receive null. I'm quite sure that the firebase part is correctly configured, but if you need screenshot just let me know. Can somebady helps me please?
    class GoogleAuthUIClient(
        private val context: Context,
        private val oneTapClient: SignInClient
    ) {
        private val auth = Firebase.auth

        suspend fun signIn() :IntentSender? {
            val result = try {
                oneTapClient.beginSignIn(
                    buildSignInRequest()
                ).await()
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                if(e is CancellationException) throw e
                null
            }
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                result?.toString() ?: "null", //always null
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            return result?.pendingIntent?.intentSender
        }

        // ...

        private fun buildSignInRequest(): BeginSignInRequest {
            return BeginSignInRequest.Builder()
                .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                    GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                        .setServerClientId(context.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                        .build()
                )
                .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                .build()
        }
    }

    //MainActivity.kt
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "sign_in"){
                        composable("sign_in") {
                            val viewModel = viewModel<SignInViewModel>()
                            val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

                            val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                                contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
                                onResult = { result ->
                                    if(result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                                        lifecycleScope.launch {
                                            val signInResult = googleAuthUIClient.signInWithIntent(
                                                intent = result.data ?: return@launch
                                            )
                                            viewModel.onSignInResult(signInResult)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )

                            LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.isSignInSuccessful) {
                                if(state.isSignInSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        applicationContext,
                                        "Sign in successful",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }

                            SignInScreen(
                                state = state,
                                onSignInClick = {
                                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                                        val signInIntentSender = googleAuthUIClient.signIn()
                                        launcher.launch(
                                            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                                                signInIntentSender ?: return@launch
                                            ).build()
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }


Before trying to debug your code, have you considered using the Credential Manager (https://developers.google.com/identity/android-credential-manager) instead? The API that you're using is already deprecated.

I'll try, thank you
